# Connecting overlay to dynamic elements

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I want to make overlay using `angular-cdk` that will be attached to dynamically created elements using `*ngFor` is ti possible?

Here is example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4a989
I want to open overlay with every button but overlay should be attached to that that opened overlay. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define property in your component:

```
triggerOrigin: any;
```

This property will be responsible for `cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin` input property of your overlay:

```
<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="triggerOrigin" 
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then create toggle method like:

```
toggle(trigger: any) {
  this.triggerOrigin = trigger;
  this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
}
```

It takes trigger instance as parameter. We will pass it from template depending on clicked button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin" (click)="toggle(trigger)">Open overlay</button>
...
<div style="margin-top:100px">
  <button *ngFor="let btn of btns" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
   (click)="toggle(trigger)">{{btn}}</button>
</div>
```

Completed example could be found on **[Forked Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aycsad?file=src/app/app.component.html)**